zsh: command not found: nodemon
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/naveenkumark/Desktop/mern/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/naveenkumark/Desktop/mern/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/naveenkumark/.npm/\_logs/2024-05-21T09_46_42_729Z-debug-0.log
zsh: command not found: nodemon
Node.js v20.13.1

I have tried to install nodemon on my MacBook Pro M1. After installing npm install nodemon package has successfully installed, but when I have change in package.json:
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2"
  }
}

Then when I had try to run nodemon server.js it results in error above.

Your package file shows you haven't installed nodemon... Based on the error about package.json not being found it seems like you're in the wrong directory entirely: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/wtf-npm/errors/enoent


npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/naveenkumark/Desktop/mern/package.json'

This means that npm could not find a package.json file in /Users/naveenkumark/Desktop/mern/ The package.json shown in the answer is not in the correct directory. To fix this, move the package.json files to /Users/naveenkumark/Desktop/mern/ and run npm install
Additionally, the package.json shows that nodemon is not installed. You can either install it locally by navigating to /Users/naveenkumark/Desktop/mern/ and running npm install nodemon or install it globally with npm install --global nodemon
